# $location.path does not refresh the page IE 10

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying to use $location.path from angular and it seems it does not refresh the page on IE 10.

Basically after user is updated I want to show the list of users.

```
 $scope.updateUser = function () {
   UserFactory.update($scope.user);
   $scope.users = UsersFactory.query();
   $location.path('/user-list');

};
```

Things are working in Mozilla Firefox.

I set additional header for disable caching in IE and it seems request is going to server (I get HTTP 200 with proper data but question is why page is not reloaded or binding is not happening in IE 10.